# Как сделать имитацию дат записей и комментариев?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть несколько блоков с записями и комментариями. Как при клике на кнопку равномерно распределить даты постов на 7 дней, и задать реалистичное время для комментариев? Количество записей и комментариев может быть произвольным.

Пример (даты изначально не заданы, рассчитываются при клике):

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="text">Текст записи (7 дней назад)</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Комментарий (7 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (5 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (5 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (3 дней назад)</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="text">Текст записи (4 дня назад)</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Комментарий (4 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (3 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (2 дней назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (1 дней назад)</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="text">Текст записи (1 день назад)</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Комментарий (1 день назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (22 часа назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (14 часов назад)</li>
        <li>Комментарий (27 минут назад)</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button class="calc_date">Показать даты</button>
```

Comment: почему для записи 7 дней назад не должно быть комментариев "1 минута назад"?

Comment: Тоже верное :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с использованием moment.js

Генерирует рандомные даты при каждом нажатии. Стартовая дата - месяц назад.

```js
var divstart,
    listart;
moment.locale('ru');

function randomDate(start, end) {
  return new moment(start.valueOf() + Math.random() * (end.valueOf() - start.valueOf()));
}

$('.calc_date').on('click', function() {
  divstart = moment().subtract(1, 'months');
  $('.text>span').each(function() {
    divstart = listart = randomDate(divstart, moment());
    $(this).text(divstart.fromNow());
    $(this).parent().next().find('span').each(function() {
      listart = randomDate(listart, moment());
      $(this).text(listart.fromNow());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/locale/ru.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="text">Текст записи  <span></span></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="text">Текст записи  <span></span></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="text">Текст записи  <span></span></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
    <li>Комментарий  <span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="calc_date">Показать даты</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
* Взять количество постов (N)
* Сгенерировать массив из N элементов, каждый из которых - рандомное целое число от 0 до 6 (число дней).
* отсортировать массив по возрастанию.
* В цикле для каждого поста:
  - задать дату, равную начальной плюс взятое из i-го элемента массива число.
  - проделать таким же способом расстановку времени для комментариев, задав рандомное число минут в промежутке от 0 до числа минут в "рабочем дне" и прибавив это число минут к времени начала "рабочего дня".
```

Answer (score -1):

набросал функцию, которая принимает количество постов или комментариев и формирует массив с этим количеством чисел от 1 до 7. Числа могут повторяться т.к. постов может быть 100 а чисел всего 7. Далее можешь сам прикрутить минуты.

```
function get_date(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 7));
    }
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    return arr;
}
```